# about Property Wrapper's initializers

Tags: swift

In the official Swift Language Guide about [Property Wrappers](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Properties.html#ID617), there it defines a property wrapper `SmallNumber` with three different initializers:

```swift
@propertyWrapper
struct SmallNumber {
    private var maximum: Int
    private var number: Int

    var wrappedValue: Int {
        get { return number }
        set { number = min(newValue, maximum) }
    }

    init() {
        maximum = 12
        number = 0
    }
    init(wrappedValue: Int) {
        maximum = 12
        number = min(wrappedValue, maximum)
    }
    init(wrappedValue: Int, maximum: Int) {
        self.maximum = maximum
        number = min(wrappedValue, maximum)
    }
}
```

my question is: wouldn't it suffice to just define one initializer with default parameters? why bother defining three?

```swift
@propertyWrapper
struct SmallNumber {
    private var maximum: Int
    private var number: Int

    var wrappedValue: Int {
        get { return number }
        set { number = min(newValue, maximum) }
    }

    // initializer with default values
    init(wrappedValue: Int = 0, maximum: Int = 12) {
        self.maximum = maximum
        number = min(wrappedValue, maximum)
    }
}
```

but it seems this code doesn't work, it crashes my Swift Playground for iPad (it supports Swift 5.1 now).

It seems to work with Swift 5.2, at least on [paiza.io](https://paiza.io/projects/lMGpqIkxyARj45EbuFsdTA).

----[ edited ]----

The code on my Swift Playgrounds for iPad:

```
@propertyWrapper
struct SmallNumber {
    
    private var max: Int
    private var number: Int
    
    var wrappedValue: Int {
        get { return number }
        set { number = min(newValue, max) }
    }
    
    init(wrappedValue: Int = 0, max: Int = 12) {
        self.max = max
        number = min(wrappedValue, max)
    }
}

struct SmallNumbers {
    @SmallNumber var n1: Int                          // init()
    @SmallNumber var n2: Int = 1                      // .init(wrappedValue:)
    @SmallNumber(wrappedValue: 2, max: 5) var n3: Int // .init(wrappedValue:max:)
    @SmallNumber(max: 9) var n4: Int = 10             // .init(wrapped:max:)
}

var s = SmallNumbers()
print(s.n1, s.n2, s.n3, s.n4)
```

and here is the screenshot:

[image: iPad screenshot]

Comment: It works for me in Xcode 12 playgrounds. Can you show how are you using the property wrapper?

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: @Sweeper I haven't try the code on Xcode playgrounds, but it doesn't work on the iPad playgrounds (supporting Swift 5.1 now).